# No log4net output in mono on a Mac

Tags: c#, mono, log4net, monodevelop, monomac

I'm trying to add log4net onto our MonoMac solution. Built fine but no log file is generated.

I've got a log4net config that works fine in a Windows application. We're referencing the CLI build log4net (for mono v2). Windows is happy with it and we get logs as expected.

Now in Mac, I've tried a separate log4net.config file (preferable) - it's built correctly and appears in the output area on the Mac, with the name referred to in the app.config.

Still no output.

I've tried putting all the config in the app.config. No difference.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well good news!
We have log4net working just fine.
As ever, it's reliant on a bang on config. We're using our usual appenders and all seems well.
We're using a seperate config file. We're using the manual configure call, not the assembly attribute.

All good. Remember to add a config file in MonoDevelop and remember to copy that to the output dir.

Job is indeed a good 'un.

If anyone else is stuck, or if it's of value, I can add our config here.

Comment: Hello @penderi, I would like to see your config file.